# When automatically importing modules from a subfolder, their imports fail

Tags: python, python-import, relative-path, python-packaging

I've read through a couple of similar questions, notably [this one about `imp.load_module`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder) which seems to be close to what I want, but I can't understand why I'm still getting ImportErrors. Here is my folder hierarchy:

```
program\
  __init__.py
  main.py
  thirdparty\
    __init__.py
    css\
      __init__.py
      css.py
      utils\
        __init__.py
        http.py
```

In `main.py` I have the following code. This is intended to search the `thirdparty\` directory and load each module it finds. Each module is in its own separate directory.

```
import os
import imp

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("thirdparty"):
    for source in (s for s in files if s.endswith(".py")):
        name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(source))[0]
        m = imp.load_module(name, *imp.find_module(name, [root]))
```

The problem is that `css.py` happens to use its own subfolder that it loads stuff off of, `utils`. It has a line in it that says:

```
from utils import http
```

And that is where it fails. I get this error when I run main.py.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    m = imp.load_module(name, *imp.find_module(name, [root]))
  File "thirdparty/css/css.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utils import http
ImportError: No module named utils
```

I'm stumped. `css.py` is self contained in its own folder, and when I run `css.py` separately it imports `utils` just fine. What is causing this?

Comment: I ran into this exact same problem. Did you ever find an answer? In Python 3 the imp module is deprecated in favor of importlib, but I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve this by changing the import to:

```
from .utils import http
```

Or by adding the folder you import to the Python Path:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(root, source))
```

When you import modules in `thirdparty`, the place Python looks for modules is still the main directory. The initial import works, because you give the right path to `imp.find_module`, but after that Python has no idea where to look for the modules.