# Python module in path: ImportError raised in mako template

Tags: python, unit-testing, mako, importerror

There is an ImportError that has the potential to drive me mad. The situation looks like this:

```
tests/
    testWebsite.py
website/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    _webtools/
        __init__.py
        templatedefs.py
        ...
    _templates/
        base.mako
        article.mako
        ...
```

The code (sans the tests directory, which I hesitate to commit, before the problem is solved) is online here: https://github.com/Boldewyn/website/.

When I call `python -m website.__main__ build`, the main routine creates from some input static HTML files using the templates under `website/_templates`. This works just fine in any given directory.

However, in the `tests/testWebsite.py` I have a unit test, that should run the same thing, too. But there the Mako templates raise import errors for files, that are imported fine in the other case.

```
$ head -n 5 website/_templates/article.mako
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
<%!
from website._webtools.templatedefs import strip_tags
%>
<%inherit file="base.mako" />
```

Running the test then yields:

```
$ python -m unittest tests.testWebsite
...
ERROR: test_initial_build (tests.testWebsite.BuildTestCase)
Check, if building directly after bootstrap works
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/testWebsite.py", line 99, in test_initial_build
  File "website/_webtools/build.py", line 89, in build
    article.save(articles=articles)
  File "website/_webtools/articles.py", line 514, in save
    template_engine.render_article(self, **ctx)
  File "website/_webtools/templates.py", line 52, in render_article
    r.render_article(article, **ctx)
  File "website/_webtools/templates.py", line 277, in render_article
    tpl = self.lookup.get_template(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/lookup.py", line 217, in get_template
    return self._load(srcfile, uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/lookup.py", line 277, in _load
    **self.template_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/template.py", line 205, in __init__
    module = self._compile_from_file(path, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/template.py", line 249, in _compile_from_file
    filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mako/template.py", line 470, in _compile_text
    exec code in module.__dict__, module.__dict__
  File "_templates_article_mako", line 16, in <module>
ImportError: No module named templatedefs
```

Now, the funny part is, that I can print `sys.path` directly from the template:

```
<%!
import sys
print sys.path
from website._webtools.templatedefs import strip_tags
%>
```

And I can confirm there, that `website` *is* in the path. Also, the import *does* work well in every other deployment scenario.

Importing `website` or `website._webtools` also works well. Only the `website._webtools.templatedefs` part goes wrong.

Has anyone an idea, where I could look to find signs of what might go wrong?

The test code is quite straight-forward:

```
class BuildTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        self.cwd = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.tmpdir)
        bootstrap(self.tmpdir, { # this initiates a new project
          "URL": "localhost",
          "TITLE": "Example",
          "DEFAULTS": {
              "AUTHOR": "John Doe",
          }
        })

    def test_initial_build(self):
        """Check, if building directly after bootstrap works"""
        build()

    def tearDown(self):
        os.chdir(self.cwd)
        shutil.rmtree(self.tmpdir)
```

**Edit:** One more diagnostic: I let mako compile the template and executed the resulting Python file stand-alone. Works like a charm. I also reduced templatedefs.py to the bare minimum (only defs returning empty strings), so that I can exclude ImportErrors (or other weirdness) in that file as well.

**System info:** Ubuntu 11.04, Python 2.7, Mako 0.3.6.

Comment: What is in your `__init__.py`s?

Comment: Not entirely sure what is wrong without seeing the complete test code.    I notice that if I import templatedefs in testWebsite.py I have no import error when build actually runs.  I suspect the os.chdir is causing you problems.

Comment: @agf see here: https://github.com/Boldewyn/website/blob/master/website/__init__.py

Comment: Welcome to python's embarrassing abortion of a packaging system! I've had extremely similar problems to this one, and it doesn't seem to be solvable unless you want to pollute your `sys.path` as you traverse the directories, or use full paths. I hope some bounty hunter proves me wrong! ([My similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981902/when-automatically-importing-modules-from-a-subfolder-their-imports-fail))

Comment: @Mike Steder: I pushed the test branch to github: https://github.com/Boldewyn/website/tree/testTest where you can see the tests folder. I, too, suspect the os.chdir, but it's just a rather vague feeling, that I'd like to have confirmed by some facts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indeed drives one mad. However here are some things:

1. `./nosetests`:
   this works and all 9 tests pass
2. `'templatedefs'` is the only key missing in `'_webtools.__dict__'` when you add an `'from website import _webtools'` to your mako template and compare `'nosetests'` to `'python -m unittest tests.testWebsite'`: the other parts were already imported earlier
3. `sys.path` contains `''` (a relative path) in the `'python -m unittest tests.testWebsite'` case, but not in the `'nosetests'` case, where `sys.path` contains only absolute paths. This results in different values for `'website._webtools.__file__'`: one is relative `['website/_webtools']`, the other is absolute `['/home/username/tmp/website/_webtools']`. Since you make a `os.chdir`, the relative paths don't work any more.

SO: If you want to use pure unittest, you can add `'import website._webtools.templatedefs'` at the beginning of your test file. This ensures that you have templatedefs imported when you run `os.chdir`.  And I would suggest to use nose. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that helped and was the problem. Thanks for the explanation! My state of mind is rescued :-)